# my theme automatically adds new pages to menu

Tags: menus, pages

I have a theme that has a problem. When I add new page in it, it automatically adds two menu item of that page. Here is my code from functions.php

```
<?php

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Left Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));

if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
    register_sidebar(array(
            'name' => 'Right Sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div class="widget">',
        'after_widget' => '</div>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>',
    ));



if (function_exists('add_theme_support')) {
    add_theme_support('menus');
}   
// Enable support for post-thumbnails

add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

if ( function_exists('add_theme_support') ) {
    add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');
}

function my_function_admin_bar(){
    return false;
}
add_filter( 'show_admin_bar' , 'my_function_admin_bar');
?>
<?php
function new_excerpt_more($more) {
       global $post;
    return '... <div class="more-link"><a href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">Read More</a></div>';
}
add_filter('excerpt_more', 'new_excerpt_more');
function new_excerpt_length($length) {
    return 65;
}
add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
?>
<?php
$themename = "my power theme";
$shortname = "mpt";
$options = array (
    array( "name" => $themename." Options",
           "type" => "title"),
    array( "type" => "open"),
    array( "name" => "Logo URL",
           "desc" => "Enter the link to your logo image",
           "id" => $shortname."_logo",
           "type" => "text",
           "std" => ""),
    array( "name" => "Google Analytics Code",
           "desc" => "Paste your Google Analytics or other tracking code in this box.",
           "id" => $shortname."_ga_code",
           "type" => "textarea",
           "std" => ""),
    array( "name" => "Feedburner URL",
           "desc" => "Paste your Feedburner URL here to let readers see it in your website",
           "id" => $shortname."_feedburner",
           "type" => "text",
           "std" => get_bloginfo('rss2_url')),
    array( "name" => "Twitter ID",
           "desc" => "Your Twitter username",
           "id" => $shortname."_twitterid",
           "type" => "text",
           "std" => ""),
    array( "name" => "Facebook Page",
           "desc" => "Link to your Facebook page, <strong>with http://</strong>",
           "id" => $shortname."_facebookid",
           "type" => "text",
           "std" => ""),

    array( "type" => "close"));
function mytheme_add_admin() {

global $themename, $shortname, $options;

if ( $_GET['page'] == basename(__FILE__) ) {

if ( 'save' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

foreach ($options as $value) {
update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ); }

foreach ($options as $value) {
if( isset( $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ] ) ) { update_option( $value['id'], $_REQUEST[ $value['id'] ]  ); } else { delete_option( $value['id'] ); } }

header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&saved=true");
die;

} else if( 'reset' == $_REQUEST['action'] ) {

foreach ($options as $value) {
delete_option( $value['id'] ); }

header("Location: themes.php?page=functions.php&reset=true");
die;

}
}

add_menu_page($themename." Options", "".$themename." Options", 'edit_themes', basename(__FILE__), 'mytheme_admin');

}
function mytheme_add_init() {  
$file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');  
wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/functions/functions.css", false, "1.0", "all");  
} 

function mytheme_admin() {

global $themename, $shortname, $options;

if ( $_REQUEST['saved'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings saved.</strong></p></div>';
if ( $_REQUEST['reset'] ) echo '<div id="message" class="updated fade"><p><strong>'.$themename.' settings reset.</strong></p></div>';

?>
<div class="wrap">
<h2><?php echo $themename; ?> Settings</h2>

<p>This theme includes jQuery Nivo Slider. To work, you must create a new category with name <strong>Featured</strong>, and include your images in a custom field named as <strong>nivoimage</strong>.<p>
<p>I suggest that you include 490x280 images only.</p>
<p>Thumbnails are not automatically added in your post. You must use your images as "featured images" when you upload any image (this theme suppports WP thumbnails feature).</p>

<form method="post">

<?php foreach ($options as $value) {
switch ( $value['type'] ) {

case "open":
?>
<table width="100%" border="0" style="background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:10px;">

<?php break;

case "close":
?>

</table><br />

<?php break;

case "title":
?>
<table width="100%" border="0" style="background-color:#F9F9F9; padding:5px 10px;"><tr>
<td colspan="2"><h3 style="font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;"><?php echo $value['name']; ?></h3></td>
</tr>

<?php break;

case 'text':
?>

<tr>
<td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
<td width="80%"><input style="width:400px;" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" value="<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo get_settings( $value['id'] ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<?php
break;

case 'textarea':
?>

<tr>
<td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
<td width="80%"><textarea name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" style="width:400px; height:200px;" type="<?php echo $value['type']; ?>" cols="" rows=""><?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) != "") { echo get_settings( $value['id'] ); } else { echo $value['std']; } ?></textarea></td>

</tr>

<tr>
<td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<?php
break;

case 'select':
?>
<tr>
<td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
<td width="80%"><select style="width:240px;" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>"><?php foreach ($value['options'] as $option) { ?><option<?php if ( get_settings( $value['id'] ) == $option) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } elseif ($option == $value['std']) { echo ' selected="selected"'; } ?>><?php echo $option; ?></option><?php } ?></select></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<?php
break;

case "checkbox":
?>
<tr>
<td width="20%" rowspan="2" valign="middle"><strong><?php echo $value['name']; ?></strong></td>
<td width="80%"><?php if(get_option($value['id'])){ $checked = "checked=\"checked\""; }else{ $checked = "";} ?>
<input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" id="<?php echo $value['id']; ?>" value="true" <?php echo $checked; ?> />
</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td><small><?php echo $value['desc']; ?></small></td>
</tr><tr><td colspan="2" style="margin-bottom:5px;border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;">&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td></tr>

<?php break;

}
}
?>

<p class="submit">
<input name="save" type="submit" value="Save changes" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="save" />
</p>
</form>
<form method="post">
<p class="submit">
<input name="reset" type="submit" value="Reset" />
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="reset" />
</p>
</form>
</div>
<?php
}add_action('admin_menu', 'mytheme_add_admin');
add_action('admin_init', 'mytheme_add_init');
?>
<?php
/***** Numbered Page Navigation (Pagination) Code.
      Tested up to WordPress version 3.1.2 *****/

/* Function that Rounds To The Nearest Value.
   Needed for the pagenavi() function */
function round_num($num, $to_nearest) {
   /*Round fractions down (http://php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php)*/
   return floor($num/$to_nearest)*$to_nearest;
}

/* Function that performs a Boxed Style Numbered Pagination (also called Page Navigation).
   Function is largely based on Version 2.4 of the WP-PageNavi plugin */
function pagenavi($before = '', $after = '') {
    global $wpdb, $wp_query;
    $pagenavi_options = array();
    $pagenavi_options['pages_text'] = ('Page %CURRENT_PAGE% of %TOTAL_PAGES%:');
    $pagenavi_options['current_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
    $pagenavi_options['page_text'] = '%PAGE_NUMBER%';
    $pagenavi_options['first_text'] = ('First');
    $pagenavi_options['last_text'] = ('Last');
    $pagenavi_options['next_text'] = 'Next &raquo;';
    $pagenavi_options['prev_text'] = '&laquo; Previous';
    $pagenavi_options['dotright_text'] = '...';
    $pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'] = '...';
    $pagenavi_options['num_pages'] = 5; //continuous block of page numbers
    $pagenavi_options['always_show'] = 0;
    $pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers'] = 0;
    $pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple'] = 5;

    //If NOT a single Post is being displayed
    /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_single)*/
    if (!is_single()) {
        $request = $wp_query->request;
        //intval � Get the integer value of a variable
        /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php*/
        $posts_per_page = intval(get_query_var('posts_per_page'));
        //Retrieve variable in the WP_Query class.
        /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var*/
        $paged = intval(get_query_var('paged'));
        $numposts = $wp_query->found_posts;
        $max_page = $wp_query->max_num_pages;

        //empty � Determine whether a variable is empty
        /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php*/
        if(empty($paged) || $paged == 0) {
            $paged = 1;
        }

        $pages_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_pages']);
        $larger_page_to_show = intval($pagenavi_options['num_larger_page_numbers']);
        $larger_page_multiple = intval($pagenavi_options['larger_page_numbers_multiple']);
        $pages_to_show_minus_1 = $pages_to_show - 1;
        $half_page_start = floor($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
        //ceil � Round fractions up (http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php)
        $half_page_end = ceil($pages_to_show_minus_1/2);
        $start_page = $paged - $half_page_start;

        if($start_page <= 0) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        $end_page = $paged + $half_page_end;
        if(($end_page - $start_page) != $pages_to_show_minus_1) {
            $end_page = $start_page + $pages_to_show_minus_1;
        }
        if($end_page > $max_page) {
            $start_page = $max_page - $pages_to_show_minus_1;
            $end_page = $max_page;
        }
        if($start_page <= 0) {
            $start_page = 1;
        }

        $larger_per_page = $larger_page_to_show*$larger_page_multiple;
        //round_num() custom function - Rounds To The Nearest Value.
        $larger_start_page_start = (round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple) - $larger_per_page;
        $larger_start_page_end = round_num($start_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_end_page_start = round_num($end_page, 10) + $larger_page_multiple;
        $larger_end_page_end = round_num($end_page, 10) + ($larger_per_page);

        if($larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple == $start_page) {
            $larger_start_page_start = $larger_start_page_start - $larger_page_multiple;
            $larger_start_page_end = $larger_start_page_end - $larger_page_multiple;
        }
        if($larger_start_page_start <= 0) {
            $larger_start_page_start = $larger_page_multiple;
        }
        if($larger_start_page_end > $max_page) {
            $larger_start_page_end = $max_page;
        }
        if($larger_end_page_end > $max_page) {
            $larger_end_page_end = $max_page;
        }
        if($max_page > 1 || intval($pagenavi_options['always_show']) == 1) {
            /*http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php */
            /*number_format_i18n(): Converts integer number to format based on locale (wp-includes/functions.php*/
            $pages_text = str_replace("%CURRENT_PAGE%", number_format_i18n($paged), $pagenavi_options['pages_text']);
            $pages_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pages_text);
            echo $before.'<div class="pagenavi">'."\n";

            if(!empty($pages_text)) {
                echo '<span class="pages">'.$pages_text.'</span>';
            }
            //Displays a link to the previous post which exists in chronological order from the current post.
            /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/previous_post_link*/
            previous_posts_link($pagenavi_options['prev_text']);

            if ($start_page >= 2 && $pages_to_show < $max_page) {
                $first_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['first_text']);
                //esc_url(): Encodes < > & " ' (less than, greater than, ampersand, double quote, single quote).
                /*http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation*/
                //get_pagenum_link():(wp-includes/link-template.php)-Retrieve get links for page numbers.
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link()).'" class="first" title="'.$first_page_text.'">1</a>';
                if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'])) {
                    echo '<span class="expand">'.$pagenavi_options['dotleft_text'].'</span>';
                }
            }

            if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_start_page_start > 0 && $larger_start_page_end <= $max_page) {
                for($i = $larger_start_page_start; $i < $larger_start_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                }
            }

            for($i = $start_page; $i  <= $end_page; $i++) {
                if($i == $paged) {
                    $current_page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['current_text']);
                    echo '<span class="current">'.$current_page_text.'</span>';
                } else {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                }
            }

            if ($end_page < $max_page) {
                if(!empty($pagenavi_options['dotright_text'])) {
                    echo '<span class="expand">'.$pagenavi_options['dotright_text'].'</span>';
                }
                $last_page_text = str_replace("%TOTAL_PAGES%", number_format_i18n($max_page), $pagenavi_options['last_text']);
                echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($max_page)).'" class="last" title="'.$last_page_text.'">'.$max_page.'</a>';
            }
            next_posts_link($pagenavi_options['next_text'], $max_page);

            if($larger_page_to_show > 0 && $larger_end_page_start < $max_page) {
                for($i = $larger_end_page_start; $i <= $larger_end_page_end; $i+=$larger_page_multiple) {
                    $page_text = str_replace("%PAGE_NUMBER%", number_format_i18n($i), $pagenavi_options['page_text']);
                    echo '<a href="'.esc_url(get_pagenum_link($i)).'" class="single_page" title="'.$page_text.'">'.$page_text.'</a>';
                }
            }
            echo '</div>'.$after."\n";
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'init', 'register_my_menus' );

function register_my_menus() {
register_nav_menus(
array(
'menu-1' => __( 'Menu 1' ),
'menu-2' => __( 'Menu 2' )
)
);
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'relatedPost', 120, 180, true );
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) {
    add_image_size( 'sliderimg', 53, 80, true );
}
?>
```

Please help me how can I rectify this problem. Thanks

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the code doing that. Please add this code to your question.

Comment: thanks toscho for your guidance. I have added my functions.php code. please have a look at it and please help me what's creating this problem. thanks

Comment: This code is a mess. If you use NetBeans please remember to use code format sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

I analyze your hard code from functions.php and my only shot is in lines with header() php function. I can't see clearly but they can redirect you and run some code twice.

Please try to comment them and look if this is the reason.

Comment: thanks maciej for your help. i have seen the code where you are pointing to, but it's an if-else statement and it's relevant to theme options and i'm having problem with my menu items on the front of the site. if you can again check the code and could tell me about the problem, it would be nice. thanks

Comment: Let's clear that: you add menu item from Apperance>Menu page, and after that you have there one or two menu items? If you have there 2 items, and on your page (on front) you have 4 - there is a problem only in your front-end files). Please answer, I will try to help you.

Comment: actually my problem is that when i add new page from Pages>Add New, without my even adding this page to my menu from Appearance>Menu, this page is added to my menu twice. Please let me know if that's make sence. If you have any query about it, I'll try to clarify it. Thanks

Comment: Link for your page will be helpfull. It looks like in your header.php file you have function which display all pages used twice or ... if you do not have set any menus (and positions for it) WP will automaticly display all pages which was created and are public.

Comment: To debug this problem you can change theme and check if this problem is theme related.